# System freezes for 5 seconds when seeking in or skipping to songs and videos

Tags: windows, video, mp3, freeze, media

When I start playing a new video or MP3 or skip to a time when playing them, my system hangs for a couple of seconds. A restart solves this problem, but only for a while. It does not matter which player I use (VLC, Media Player, Winamp, Zoom Player), which media files or if they are located on a network drive or on the local hard drive. Everything else works flawlessly and after the playing has started, there are not problems - until I switch to another file.

Additionally, when the Winamp playlist continues to the next song, the system does not hang. When I skip to the next song manually, the system hangs.

I've been using Windows XP for years and consider myself a fairly professional windows user, but I have no idea what could cause this.

Dual-core 2Ghz, 2GB RAM, Windows XP SP3, Audigy card with kxproject. Worked flawlessly for years.

Would be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: How many programs are you running in the background?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. Also Windows XP SP3, also Audigy card, and also kxproject. I managed to solve it by changing kX playback buffer size: right-click on kxmixer icon > Settings > Setup buffers. Then try a few different values for the second value.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when some network share is unaccessible or slow. If you see this even if you try to open a normal document, or even browsing with file explorer, than this can be the cause. Check your network shares, disconnect few/all of them and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Do these diagnostic steps when the problem occurs:

1. Try to disable your virus scanner and firewall because they might be slowing down the file access or album information request or something like that. In the trend of Sunny his answer, you can try to pull the internet cable too.
2. Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and make sure that the Update Speed under the View menu is set low enough. After a freeze occurs you can then look to see what process is causing this behaviour.
3. If you have the guts to go for a hard solution, look at a trace you can create with [XPerf](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303142051/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pigscanfly/archive/2008/02/16/using-xperf-to-take-a-trace.aspx) or take it to the [Sysinternals Forums](https://forum.sysinternals.com/) where they can help you with such trace or other tools like [ADPlus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-windows-startup).
4. In the worst case, your hard drive is failing and can only keep up with caching the song.